# Jquery Scripts stop working after infinite scroll loads new pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to load one script which is working fine on first page but once the infinite scroll load the new page that js functionality is not showing up there.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var original = $('.load_more_text a').attr('href');
var new_href = original.replace('/page/', '/?page=');

$('.load_more_text a').attr('href', new_href);
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').text('Sold');
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().addClass('green');
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().parent().parent().addClass('green_pr');

})
</script>
```

what am i missing ?

Comment: you need to call the function after infinite scroll loads the next page also.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan can you tell me how ? as i want to load this function on every page load 
`$('.load_more_text a').attr('href', new_href);
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').text('Sold');
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().addClass('green');
$('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().parent().parent().addClass('green_pr');`

Comment: how are you doing infinite scroll???

Comment: `var original = $('.load_more_text a').attr('href');

    var new_href = original.replace('/page/', '/?page=');` This is a code for infinite scroll. the site on wp just for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function after infinite scroll loads
example

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//YOUR SCRIPT infinite scroll load
$.ajax({
        url: newUrl,
        type: "GET",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            loadtext(); //call the function after infinite scroll loads
        },
    });


function loadtext(){
    var original = $('.load_more_text a').attr('href');
    var new_href = original.replace('/page/', '/?page=');

    $('.load_more_text a').attr('href', new_href);
    $('.prod_meta span.winned-for').text('Sold');
    $('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().addClass('green');
    $('.prod_meta span.winned-for').parent().parent().parent().addClass('green_pr');
}

})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. this is the ` var original = $('.load_more_text a').attr('href');
    var new_href = original.replace('/page/', '/?page=');`
 these two lines are used for the infinite scroll